# Code completion Pydev Django Model Foreign Key Field

Tags: python, django, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

Code completion in Eclipse/pydev works decent for me. However there is one thing that does not work like I want it to. Consider the following django model:

```
class ReletionTree(models.Model):
    mother = models.ForeignKey('RelationTree', blank=True, null=True)
    father = models.ForeignKey('RelationTree', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField()

rt = RelationTree.objects.get(name='Mary') #assume unique on Mary
```

Now to the problem:

```
rt.        #--> will code complete and give me options mother/father/name
rt.mother. #--> will not code complete into mother/father/name, it will code 
           #    complete as if isinstance(rt.mother, models.ForeignKey) (I think)
```

Is there a way to make Pydev understand that I want it to code complete Foreign Keys 
as if they where of the type to which it points (in above case RelationTree and not models.ForeignKey)

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it very much (I also do Django and Eclipse), because Pydev isn't smart enough to understand the weird metaclass that Django uses to transform `father = models.ForeignKey()` to `father = RelationTree()` or whatever.

Python is really hard for autocompleters to parse, and PyDev and PyLint seem to completely give up when it comes to metaclasses.  (pylint always complains that my model classes have no `objects` member!)

Answer (score 0):

Some 3+ years later and my 6 month project is still not finished (=. However I now know that:

1. You should use *[pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)* instead of *eclipse+pyDev*. Their free edition is a much better for python development in my opinion.
2. Pycharm professional edition also supports django code completion. It saves me **a lot** of time.